# If Variables as words

Tags: if-statement, basic

Very new to programming and I'm stuck. The code is not 100% finished but should still work. I'm having a problem with using an if statement that equals a variable with words. I just added the quotes and its hanging out that but before I added the quotes it said that if the case was selected then all the If statements were true and added 1 to each of them. Below is what I have. Also just a side question unrelated to this how do I add a variable result to the middle of a sentence? I have only been able to add them to the beginning or end.

(program starts)

```
WesternMarried=0
WesternSingle=0
WesternDivorced=0
WesternSeperated=0
EasternMarried=0
EasternSingle=0
EasternDivorced=0
EasternSeperated=0
SouthernMarried=0
SouthernSingle=0
SouthernDivorced=0
SouthernSeperated=0
MidwesternMarried=0
MidwesternSingle=0
MidwesternDivorced=0
MidwesternSeperated=0
Print "Which state is subject 1 from?"
Input State1
Print "What is the relationship status of Subject1?"
Input Relation1
Select Case State1
Case CA
    Print "You are from the western region"
    If (Relation1 = "Married") then
    WesternMarried = WesternMarried + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1 = "Single") then
    WesternSingle = WesternSingle + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1 = "Divorced") then
    WesternDivorced = WesternDivorced + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1 = "Seperated") then
    WesternSeperated = WesternSeperated + 1
    End If
Case Else
    Print "You might be from the midwestern states"
    If (Relation1 = "Married") then
    MidwesternMarried = MidwesternMarried + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1 = "Single") then
    MidwesternSingle = MidwesternSingle + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1 = "Divorced") then
    MidwesternDivorced = MidwesternDivorced + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1 = "Seperated") then
    MidwesternSeperated = MidwesternSeperated + 1
    End If
End Select
Print "The number of people married in the midwestern states is " ; MidwesternMarried
Print "The number of people single in the midwestern states is " ; MidwesternSingle
Print "The number of people divorced in the midwestern states is " ; MidwesternDivorced
Print "The number of people separated in the Western states is " ; MidwesternSeperated
Print "The number of people married in the Western states is " ; WesternMarried
Print "The number of people single in the Western states is " ; WesternSingle
Print "The number of people divorced in the Western states is " ; WesternDivorced
Print "The number of people separated in the Western states is " ; WesternSeperated
End
```

Comment: I believe you use ampersands to "add" a variable to the string, e.g. `Print MidwesternMarried & " people are married in the midwestern states"`. In the middle it would be like this `"String text " & MidwesternMarried & " more text"`

Comment: Ok ill test that out. Im still having a problem though with my If (relation1 = "Married") then statement if you know how to do that. Before I added the " " to the variable it would make all the find the case for the state but then it would find each if statement true no matter the answer. With the quotes it just wont move past it.

Comment: @user3407869 My previous comment about the ampersands is incorrect. However if you replace the ampersands in my comment with semicolons `;` then it would be correct `"String text "; MidwesternMarried; " more text"`

Comment: Seems to work I tried that before and it wouldnt. Not sure what I did wrong before. But I know it works now so must have been something I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is a better way to do it. If you don't have quotations around your strings then it will think that it is a variable. Also, you need to have the $ after your variables, this signifies that it is a string.

```
WesternMarried=0
WesternSingle=0
WesternDivorced=0
WesternSeperated=0
EasternMarried=0
EasternSingle=0
EasternDivorced=0
EasternSeperated=0
SouthernMarried=0
SouthernSingle=0
SouthernDivorced=0
SouthernSeperated=0
MidwesternMarried=0
MidwesternSingle=0
MidwesternDivorced=0
MidwesternSeperated=0
Print "Which state is subject 1 from?"
Input State1$
Print "What is the relationship status of Subject1?"
Input Relation1$
Select Case State1
Case "CA"
    Print "You are from the western region"
    If (Relation1$ = "Married") then
       WesternMarried = WesternMarried + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1$ = "Single") then
       WesternSingle = WesternSingle + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1$ = "Divorced") then
       WesternDivorced = WesternDivorced + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1$ = "Seperated") then
       WesternSeperated = WesternSeperated + 1
    End If
Case Else
    Print "You might be from the midwestern states"
    If (Relation1$ = "Married") then
       MidwesternMarried = MidwesternMarried + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1$ = "Single") then
       MidwesternSingle = MidwesternSingle + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1$ = "Divorced") then
       MidwesternDivorced = MidwesternDivorced + 1
    End If
    If (Relation1$ = "Seperated") then
       MidwesternSeperated = MidwesternSeperated + 1
    End If
End Select
Print "The number of people married in the midwestern states is " ; MidwesternMarried
Print "The number of people single in the midwestern states is " ; MidwesternSingle
Print "The number of people divorced in the midwestern states is " ; MidwesternDivorced
Print "The number of people separated in the Western states is " ; MidwesternSeperated
Print "The number of people married in the Western states is " ; WesternMarried
Print "The number of people single in the Western states is " ; WesternSingle
Print "The number of people divorced in the Western states is " ; WesternDivorced
Print "The number of people separated in the Western states is " ; WesternSeperated
End
```

**Update:** When I saw "basic" in the title I assumed you meant VB. I have now learned BASIC is actually the language that VB is based off of... Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I changed the If statement and it is still sticking at the same place. It wont get past the first If statement.

Comment: I have updated the answer to fix what I suspect the problem is. Also, take a look at this site http://www.beagle-ears.com/lars/engineer/how_comp/basic.htm

Comment: Yep that did it thank you. The Select Case State1 needs a $ at the end. It worked once I added that. Thank you very much for the help. Taking an online Programming class. I think I know for the future I should not try and take them online I need to ask the teacher certain things sometimes. But thanks for the help. I will be able to finish it now. Only thing I was stuck on.

Comment: No problem. Yes, I just caught the State1 as well. It has been updated again. Also I realized that the variable suffixes in VB seem to be the same as BASIC for the most part. http://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/VUD113/NO333718332.htm

Comment: Ok I saved both of those sites. Hopefully that helps me with the things that I dont understand. Thanks again.